# print selected element of an array using awk one line

Tags: awk

Say I have a file content as given below

cat file1

```
A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7
B1 B2 B3 B4 B5
X1
Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4 Y5 Y6 Y7 Y8 Y9
Z1 Z2 Z3
```

How do I can selectively print selected elements of this array with some kind of field separator using AWK one line solution if possible.
 
I want to select and print 3rd field of first line,2nd field of 2n line,1st field of 3rd line,9th field of 4th line and 2nd field of 5th line.

```
A3:B2:X1:Y9:Z2
```

where the field separator is ":"

Comment: Please include the code you have tried.

Comment: This is some unclear. Is `A1 A2` etc values.  What do you select?  It seems to me that you can just use `echo "A3:B2:X1:Y9:Z2"` than you get what you are asking for. I do not see the connection to the table.

Comment: How do you know which are the fields you want to print out?

Answer (score 0):

Try following `awk` command

```
awk 'BEGIN {ORS=":"; str="3:2:1:9:2"; split(str,a,":")} {print $a[NR]}' file1
```